# knitrBootstrap to HTML latency issues

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, knitrbootstrap

I recently upgraded to what I believe is still the most current version of r-studio and knitrBootstrap and have run into latency issues during the rendering process converting a `sample.utf8.md -- to html`.

When I run a simple example (http://rawgit.com/jimhester/knitrBootstrap/master/vignettes/cars.html) to generate a `knitrBootstrap::bootstrap_document` the document has no issues generating.

When I take a much longer report that used to render in minutes with older versions of markdown/knitrBootstrap, it gets hung up on the conversion process.  When I render the same file as a html_document, the HTML generates in minutes.  Wondering if there are any known issues which might cause the discrepancy in render time or any steps I should take to troubleshoot.

Option setup is as follows:

```
output:
  knitrBootstrap::bootstrap_document:
    title: "Sample Report"
    theme: cerulean
    highlight: google code
    theme.chooser: FALSE
    highlight.chooser: FALSE
    menu: FALSE
```

Option Chunks Include:

```
opts_chunk$set(cache = FALSE, dev = 'png', bootstrap.thumbnail.size= 'col-md-
12', bootstrap.thumbnail = TRUE, bootstrap.show.code= FALSE)
```

I believe I am using the most recent versions of knitr, knitrBootstrap and r-studio

`knitr_1.6.14
knitrBootstrap_1.0.0 
R-Studio Version 0.98.1017`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a previous issue related to this (https://github.com/jimhester/knitrBootstrap/issues/47), JJ mentioned they saw this problem due to pandoc trying to parse citations.  I would guess that is likely what was causing the original slowdown.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out updating to the preview version (Version 0.98.1049) of R-Studio & installing the newest version of Pandoc (pandoc 1.13.1) seemed to do the trick.  Not sure if there was a previous version of Pandoc on my machine causing issues, but HTML now renders within 60 seconds.